Models that force regression predictions to sum to 100?
I have a dataset with some covariates and a response variable which is a composition of 3 classes (A,B,C).
For example, in the observed data: Person 1 (80% A , 15 % B , 5% C), Person 2 (50% A, 20% B, 30% C).
I want to make a regression model which predicts given some values of these covariates for a person, what is the composition of a given person.
The problem is that that if I make separate regression models for each class, the predictions are not guaranteed to add to 100%.
I was thinking that maybe I can use some variable transforms to add this constraint into the model?
For example, if I transform the dependent variables into log-odds ratios by choosing one class as a reference category (eg. class C as reference).
Compute (Where $p_A$, $p_B$, and $p_C$ are the percentages for each class):
$$r_A = \log(\frac{p_A}{p_C})$$
$$r_B = \log(\frac{p_B}{p_C})$$
From here I run regular linear regressions for these ratios. If we have predictors $x_1$ and $x_2$ , we get:
$$r_A = \beta_{A0} + \beta_{A1}x_1 + \beta_{A2}x_2$$
$$r_B = \beta_{B0} + \beta_{B1}x_1 + \beta_{B2}x_2$$
To get back to predicted  percentages, I think I can then use the inverse?
$$p_A = \frac{e^{r_A}}{1 + e^{r_A} + e^{r_B}}$$
$$p_B = \frac{e^{r_B}}{1 + e^{r_A} + e^{r_B}}$$
$$p_C = \frac{1}{1 + e^{r_A} + e^{r_B}}$$
I think this is logical because now everything adds to 1:
$$p_A + p_B + p_C = \frac{e^{r_A}}{1 + e^{r_A} + e^{r_B}} + \frac{e^{r_B}}{1 + e^{r_A} + e^{r_B}} + \frac{1}{1 + e^{r_A} + e^{r_B}}$$
$$p_A + p_B + p_C = \frac{e^{r_A} + e^{r_B} + 1}{1 + e^{r_A} + e^{r_B}}$$
$$p_A + p_B + p_C = 1$$
Is this approach statistically correct?

Yes, that's called the softmax function and is what is traditionally used for this. It's commonly done for neural network, when predicting classes with gradient boosted decision trees, or modeling (e.g. with the brms R package using  family=cagtegorical()).

ah ok i did not know it had a name... I wonder if this softmax approach  will produce logical confidence intervals as well?

This is [tag:compositional-data]. Look through that tag here, or use the term in searching.

I did not know there was a specific name for this ... thank you!

Depending on the nature of the data underlying the percentage values for each individual, this might also be handled by multinomial regression.

so IMO the 'softmax'/multinomial regression approaches are inappropriate and OP is looking for compositional-data/dirichlet regression.http://r-statistics.co/Dirichlet-Regression-With-R.html?utm_content=cmp-true. since the multinomial is expecting a datapoint of the winning class, whereas OP's datapoint is a proportion

What you have is a version of a simplex. The Dirichlet distribution will achieve these constraints as long as you are happy to rescale so that predictions sum to 1. Conveniently, brms will also handle this type of data

what advantages do compositional regression/dirichlet regression have over the method in my question?

so you are calculating an expectation of log[p_a/p_c] but you are actually interested in E[p_a] ( I would assume). what you propose is AFAIK one method of compositional regression see eg https://jds-online.org/journal/JDS/article/136/file/pdf  Additive log-ratio transformation
